# Python manage.py runserver does not work with new or existing projects in my PC

Tags: django, python-3.x

rsonal\website>python manage.py runserver

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x0000028159B61048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 123, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 427, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in **init**
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in **init**
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 268, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 242, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 243, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 243, in 
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 96, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0004_auto_20190704_0341 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('admin', '0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices')

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling Django? Looks like the migrations for the admin app have messed up somehow

Comment: Yes yes I've tried that... But never worked is there an alternative way to solve this ?? Am stuck for 3 weeks!!! Or is there a way to run server through python -m?